# Image not resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS and I'm using Stylish to edit websites to help myself learn.

I'm editing the Cookie Clicker website because it looks too small on my monitor. I'm trying to make the Cookie bigger but I can't figure it out.

The HTML is at http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

and the CSS that I'm pretty sure I should be changing is

```
#bigCookie {
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -128px;
    top: -128px;
    background: url(img/perfectCookie.png);
    background-size: 256px 256px;
    background: url(img/empty.png);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 128px;
}
```

I'm trying to get it from 256px to 512px

Comment: did you try changing all the places where it says 256 to 512?

Comment: The thing is that is an image drawn on a canvas through JavaScript. The div isn't really containing the image which is why changing the values of the div isn't getting you anywhere. Since you're working on CSS I am not sure you're interested, but if you look in the main.js file you'll see where he's drawing the "perfectCookie.png" in the canvas element.

Comment: Is there a way I can have this the same every time I load the page like Stylish

Comment: @JohnAckerman 
 
Is there a way I can have this the same every time I load the page like Stylish

Answer (score 0):

```
width:512px;
height:512px;
```

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whoever styled it in the first place knows exactly what they were doing, you can see that in the comment here but this pulls out another cookie png, play with the size and positioning of it. The only thing is it doesn't have the hoverstate:

```
width: 512px;
height: 512px;
position:absolute;
left:-256px;
top:-256px;
background:url(img/perfectCookie.png);
//background-size:256px 256px;
//background:url(img/empty.png);/* somehow necessary; an empty div with no background seems to be click-through */
```

Comment: The thing is that is an image drawn on a canvas through JavaScript. The div isn't really containing the image which is why changing the values of the div isn't getting you anywhere. Since you're working on CSS I am not sure you're interested, but if you look in the main.js file you'll see where he's drawing the "perfectCookie.png" in the canvas element. – John Ackerman

Comment: Just found that it's done via javascript, was about to post

var d=128*(2-me.close);//*Game.BigCookieSize;

Comment: I don't think any css will have an affect on it, at least not to the best of my knowledge. Not sure how you would go about implementing what you want